# Why did my Denoising disappeared?

Tags: denoise

[image]

Hello guys I need a little help, the Denoiser below Adaptive Sampling suddenly disappeared. How can I enable it back?

Answer (score 2):

It's now placed in the *View Layer Properties*, see screenshot. But actually I would use the *Denoise* node in the *Compositor*, because the *Denoising* option slows down the render and the result is inferior to the *Denoise* node from my experience.

[image: denoising]

Just plug it inbetween your render and the composite output, the result is usually far better than the *Denoising* even if you don't use any additional *Denoising Data* in the *Normal* and *Albedo* inputs.

[image: denoise node]

Comment: Hello Gordon, thank you I found the Denoise in the View Layer but it used to be in the Render Properties, and it has NLM and OpenImageDenoiser.

Comment: I know it used to be in the _Render Properties_, I just told you where it is now. Sometimes when new versions of Blender come out things change, that's how it goes.

Comment: @sanaaa : please check Gordon's answer as right - because it is right. Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is right sorry

Comment: @Chris At least you've tried it  ;)

Comment: i always try....although my knowledge is very tiny... :D but i am learning ;)

Comment: @sanaaa: i think, you tapped on this  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwxk0.png up arrow button, right? Please tap on the checkmark (in my case green, in your case still gray)  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zszp8.png below it. This means "Gordon has helped me, and i am thankful for that" ;)